# Angular 2 Material Combobox

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am using Angular 2 material UI for my application, and I trying to make a form in which 2 fields has a combobox but while research about that I came to conclusion that the combobox doesn't exist for material UI. So my question, is there any work around for this issue, as it is important for me to use the combobox in my application?

Comment: I am implementing a combo box. what is that your expectation I can add to my feature

Answer (score 3):

I was able to use the Autocomplete control to achieve this. It has a defined list of items to pick from and you can also enter text... https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

Comment: How do you manage selection of an existing item having an ID but typing in a new item being just text?

Answer (score -3):

You could use the select component of Material, which is basically the same deal as a combo box.

https://material.angular.io/components/component/select

Comment: It's not the same as a combo box, since a combo box incorporates a textbox, which is not included in the select box.